# Как добавить display: none; в разметке html по клику?

Tags: javascript, html

Как добавить `style="display: none;"` для `test-class1` в разметке html по клику на кнопку без присвоения css-класса с `display: none;`?

```html
<button class="test-class1">Скрыть</button>

<div class="test-class2">Скрой меня!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае:

```
Ваша_кнопка.addEventListener('click', function(){
  Скрываемый_элемент.style.display = "none";
});
```

Часто таких пар кнопка-блок бывает много, поэтому можно писать для списка элементов, а не конкретно одного. А если часто в коде будет встречаться такое изменение свойства, бывает удобно написать короткую функцию:

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

for( let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++ ){
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    display( bubu[i], "none" );    
    
    console.log( 'Индекс i = ' + i );
  });
}

function display(elems, value){
  value = value || "block"; 
  // Если функцию вызвать только с одним аргументом, второй будет "block"
  
  if( elems instanceof HTMLElement ){  
    // Если elems - один HTML-элемент
    elems.style.display = value;    
    // изменится свойство элемента и выполнение функции прервется из-за return.
    return;
  }
  
  // А можно передать список элементов и одним вызовом скрыть все.
  for( let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ){
    elems[i].style.display = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Скрыть</button>
<div class="bubu">Скрой меня!</div><br>

<button class="btn">Скрыть</button>
<div class="bubu">Скрой меня!</div><br>

<button class="btn">Скрыть</button>
<div class="bubu">Скрой меня!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('.test-class1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.target.style.display='none';
})
```

```html
<button class="test-class1">Скрыть</button>

<div class="test-class2">Скрой меня!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

универсальный компонент, который помогает вам в скрытии каких-либо элементов по нажатию на какого-то родителя, целей (target) может быть сколько угодно

```js
class HiddenElements {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.target = this.node.getAttribute('data-target');

    if (!this.target)
      throw new Error('Missing required parameter "data-target"');

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
  }

  onClick() {
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-name=${this.target}]`);

    this.hide(targets);
  }

  hide(targets) {
    [...targets].forEach(target => target.classList.add('hide'));
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-widget="hide"]')].forEach(node => new HiddenElements(node));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

[data-widget="hide"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-widget="hide" data-target="target1">Click to hide targets with data-name="target1" attribute</div>

<div class="block" data-name="target1">1st target of target1</div>

<div class="block" data-name="target1">2td target of target1</div>

<div class="block" data-widget="hide" data-target="target2">Click to hide targets with data-name="target2" attribute</div>

<div class="block" data-name="target2">1st target of target2</div>
```